# Filter array of objects between Dates that uses AM/PM in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing a web application in Angular 8 (TypeScript) and Firebase Firestore. I have documents with a field called `createdAt` as a type `firebase.firestore.Timestamp`. I'm using AM/PM to save the dates in Firestore.

```
export interface Client {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
}
```

The array that I want to filter is (this is what I receives from Firestore):

```
const clients = [  
   {  
      "createdAt":{  
         "seconds": 1564753299,
         "nanoseconds": 89000000
      },
      "id":1,
      "name":"Juana",
   },
   {  
      "createdAt":{  
         "seconds": 1564753323,
         "nanoseconds": 418000000
      },
      "id":2,
      "name":"",
   },
   {  
      "createdAt":{  
         "seconds": 1564839675,
         "nanoseconds": 906000000
      },
      "id":3,
      "name":"Ramon",
   },
   {
      "createdAt":{  
         "seconds": 1564839684,
         "nanoseconds": 944000000
      },
      "id":4,
      "name":"",
   }
];
```

I'm trying to filter the array like this:

```
  filterClients() {
    const from = new Date(this.fromDate.year, this.fromDate.month - 1, this.fromDate.day, 0, 0, 0);
    const to = new Date(this.toDate.year, this.toDate.month - 1, this.toDate.day, 23, 59, 0);

      this.clients = this.clientsCopy.filter(client => 
        client.createdAt.toDate().getTime() >= from.getTime() && 
        client.createdAt.toDate().getTime() <= to.getTime());
  }
```

If I filter the array from Aug 2 to Aug 3, the data from Aug 3 is missing. What I'm doing wrong while comparing the dates? I saw other solutions and I have tried them, but, for some reason in my case, the comparison is skipping data.

My goal is to filter the array to get only the data between a range of dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem probably is more related to using the `Date` API in JavaScript with local timezones correctly. If you compare two dates by their Unix timestamps (`date.getTime()`), you have to ensure that both were either based on UTC or your local time zone (or other uniform time zone) at construction time of the date.

I could imagine, that the timestamps are saved in UTC format in Firebase. When you define your date filter ranges like this,

```
const from = new Date(2019, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0);
const to = new Date(2019, 7, 3, 23, 59, 0);
```

a Date will be constructed that considers your local timezone and adjusts its underlying Unix timestamp (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax)). `Firebase: UTC <--> client: local timezone`, so you compare apples with oranges.

You could use [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) to construct your client dates:

```
const from = new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0));
const to = new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 7, 3, 23, 59, 0));
```

or use one of the Date [conversion methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype).

Hope, that helps out.